# Is this a secure way to connect with Tor?

Tags: linux, tor

I was discussing the use of tor with a friend, and he happened to suggest a way to remain secure when using applications on the terminal (Lynx, Nmap etc.)

His suggestion was this:

```
ssh-keygen -b 4096
ssh -D 8008 user@127.0.0.1
```

And also add `Socks4Proxy 127.0.0.1:8008` to `/etc/tor/torrc`

I understand what the SSH commands are. But why is this more secure than using something like

```
proxychains iceweasel www.google.com
```

... (replace iceweasel with whatever app you want), Proxychains is set up to use tor automatically, I also change static to dynamic.

Could someone explain if this is secure, and why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it doesn't provide any additional security, and I don't see the point of your friend for suggesting that.

```
ssh -D 8008 user@127.0.0.1
```

Connects to your local machine creating a SOCKS proxy on 8008 (the `ssh-keygen -b 4096` above is only needed once, and is used for not requesting a passphrase from you)

> And also add Socks4Proxy 127.0.0.1:8008 to /etc/tor/torrc

This [makes tor exit through the proxy socks](https://www.torproject.org/docs/tor-manual.html.en#Socks4Proxy) on 8008… which is the same as your own machine, so you gain nothing.

And you additionally need to configure the proxy (either with proxychains or local program configuration) on any application you want to use.

I see two possibilities:

```
* Your friend got confused and somehow thought that the proxy went in the opposite direction (ie. that it was ssh what connected through the proxy, and that tor listened on `Socks4Proxy` instead of connecting there)
* That instead of `127.0.0.1` (which always refers to your own computer) he meant connecting to a different host (you need a ssh account there). In that case tor would be connecting from that machine ip (as if tor client was running there). That would add one hop if someone «broke tor», although it's possible that you would be as easily found,  by looking which account started those connections.
```

Comment: But, doesn't it encrypt everything going through the ssh tunnel?

Comment: Yes, but since you're connecting to yourself you're also decrypting the traffic.  The traffic is going to exit your network interface after the decryption.